# php compile with old openssl

Tags: php, configuration, compilation

apache (on centos) use openssl 1.0.1

**I want to compile php with different openssl vesrion.**

first I install openssl with config

> ./config --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl

then I install php with configuration

> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs
>   --disable-phpdbg --with-openssl --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/bin --disable-phpdbg-webhelper --with-mcrypt --with-pdo-mysql=/usr --with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config --enable-calendar --enable-ftp --enable-soap --with-curl --with-mcrypt --enable-opcache --enable-mbstring  --enable-bcmath --enable-sockets --with-mhash  --with-gd --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-ttf --with-gettext --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/lib

header version change successful but library version did not change

phpinfo

> OpenSSL Library Version - OpenSSL 1.0.1
>
> OpenSSL Header Version - OpenSSL 0.9.8

what i did wrong?

p.s. sorry for old question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `--with-openssl-dir` directive is not linking to the updated openssl version. Identify the right directory and adjust `--with-openssl-dir` to that path.